# clone text from textarea tag to div tag

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor like doc text editor in my webpage.
After writing some text, that should to be converted in doc document.
My problem is:

CKEditor use the textarea with HTMLEscape format.

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">  
     <h2 style="text-align: center;">TEST TEXT</h2>                                
</textarea>
```

The plugin that I'm using is **jQuery Word Export**, to get the HTML text from div only, not from textarea of CKEditor.

If change textarea tag to div and then I write with CKEditor, jQuery Word Export, export a empty text, but if I change in the source code and write inside div tag something like `<h2>Hello</h2>` (something in HTML), jQuery Word Export works fine.

http://markswindoll.github.io/jquery-word-export/

MY idea is obtain the text from textarea and then clone it into a div to get after from jQuery Word Export.

How can to do that?

Comment: Can't you just use string `replace()` before creating the word doc?

Comment: Thanks i found something like 

 `$("#some-div").text($("#some-textarea").val()).html(function(index, old) { return old.replace(/\n/g, '<br />') });`

Thats works?, how can i use?